# vagrant error: Could not resolve host: (nil); Host not found

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows

### When running "vagrant up" command, I got following error:

The box 'ubuntu/trusty32' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/trusty32"]

### Error: Could not resolve host: (nil); Host not found

Host OS: Windows 7 (64bit)
Vagrant version: 1.7.4
Git client:

I have tried following and none of them fixed the problem:
1) add "config.vm.box_check_update=false" to Vagrantfile
2) add "HTTP_PROXY" and "HTTPS_PROXY" environmental variables in host OS

(Note: I am able to download the box file using browser from atlas.hashicopr.com using actual URL.)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error it looks like that you are running vagrant under some firewall. To avoid this error simply set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variable. To get your proxy setting you may use command or easy and visual way open IE and get it from internet connection settings.

Here is how you set-

```
http_proxy=http://yourproxyserver:port
https_proxy=https://yourproxyserver:port
```

And command to get it-

```
netsh.exe winhttp show proxy
```

In output look for the of "Proxy Servers(s)".

Hope it helps.